# Query to get summary of survey questions answered (distinct column values)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a survey form and everytime someone completes the survey, a record is created in the `survey_result` table.

That table has a column for each question. Most are mutl-choice, some are free-text.

i.e. columns in table:

```
happy_or_sad (no. yes, sometimes)
are_you_busy (no, yes, sometimes)
your_suggestion
```

Now I want to display a summary of the multi-choice answers that have been submitted.

Question: Happy or Sad?
no (40%)  yes (20%) sometimes (40%)

(or at least a count if percentage is too much work). What would be the most effecient query or queries I could use to get this?

Comment: I found this http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/10/05/how-to-count-values-with-mysql-queries/ which is close but it requires knowing and hardcoding the distinct multi-choice options for each col. Maybe I'm better to just do it all in PHP(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    (SUM(happy_or_sad = 'no') / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS percentage_no,
    (SUM(happy_or_sad = 'yes') / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS percentage_yes,
    (SUM(happy_or_sad = 'sometimes') / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS percentage_sometimes,
FROM
    survey_result
```

Comment: Thanks man, that's exactly what I need. I do have about 20 odd Questions so this will be a long and slow query but it's only run by the administrator so shouldn't be a big load on the server